# What kind of insect is it?

Tags: species-identification

I found it hanging on the wall at night. It was approximately an inch long. Near my dormitory there is a lot of birch trees. The photo was taken in Prague, Czech Republic.
[image]

Comment: It is a moth in the family Noctuidae. I don't know the species.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the [heart and dart moth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heart_and_dart) (Agrotis exclamationis). Its name refers to the special black spots, which have shape of dart and heart.

[image]

---

This moth is one of the most common in the Paleoarctic ecozone. It has a wingspan of 35-44 mm. The larva of this moth is brown above and grey below. It is capable of feeding itself on a variety of plants.